# Prevent windows forms datagridview to change row after cell edit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview in windows forms, the default behavior when editing values is that after the edition of a cell, when I press enter, the selected row changes to the next.

[image]

I don't want that, I want to exit edit mode but staying in the same cell.

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Definately, I have searched but didn't found it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize the `DataGridView` to override the `ProcessDialogKey` method:

```
public class CustomGrid : DataGridView {            
        protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData) {
            if (keyData == Keys.Enter) {    
                EndEdit();
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

KeyDown event:

If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then e.SuppressKeyPress = True

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. While editing save the `cellindex` in a variable and then re-select it.

Get the column and row index:

```
e.ColumnIndex;
e.RowIndex;
```

and save them into a variable. After edited the cell, re-select the cell:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rindex].Cells[cindex].Selected = true;
```